# Android: Dynamically creating a large number of imageviews in a listView custom framelayout

Tags: android, listview, dynamic

I threw myself in a task that might be a little too difficult for me. 
I'm designing an medical application that displays images of a patient's scan and superimposes several contours that delineate organs.

The patient's scan is a series of PNG images (the background of slices listview rows). 
The contours are vectors and a same scan slice may contain several dozens of contours.

To do so, Scan slices are loaded in a listview with custom adapter. Contours are added according to a previously done selection of organs. Contours are imageViews with transparent background added over the scan in a same framelayout. Therefore, imageviews of contours are added dynamically in the layout.

The problem is that I might be asking too much from listview. In fact, I'm getting stuck with the getView method of the adapter. Contours appear, but refresh and iteration through slices seems to be at random.

Could someone throw me a hint about this situation? I'm not sure the dynamic allocation of imageviews is that clever now... What could I do?

Any help would be welcome !

Adapter:

```
package bhouse.radiovolumes;

import android.content.Context;
import android.media.Image;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by kranck on 8/3/2017.
 */

public class ScannerListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<SliceItem> {
    private Context context;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private ArrayList<SliceItem> slices;

    public ScannerListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<SliceItem> slices) {
        super(context, R.layout.list_view_scan, slices);
        this.context = context;
        this.slices = slices;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder holder;

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.list_view_scan, parent, false);
            convertView.setMinimumHeight(parent.getMeasuredHeight());
            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.scanView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.view_scan);
            holder.frameLayout = (FrameLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.zoomLayout);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        SliceItem item = getItem(position);
        int resIdScan = this.context.getResources().getIdentifier(item.getStorageLocation(), "drawable", context.getPackageName());
        Picasso
                .with(context)
                .load(resIdScan)
                .error(R.drawable.borabora)
                .into(holder.scanView);


        for (int i = 0; i < item.getVectorStorageLocation().size(); i++) {
            ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
            String resourceName = "cylindre__2___" + String.valueOf(position);
            int resId = context.getResources().getIdentifier(resourceName, "drawable", context.getPackageName());
            imageView.setImageResource(resId);
            holder.frameLayout.addView(imageView);
        }
        return convertView;
    }


    static class ViewHolder {
        FrameLayout frameLayout;
        ImageView scanView;
    }
}
```

Layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
<bhouse.radiovolumes.ZoomView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"

android:layout_centerInParent="true" >

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/zoomLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/view_scan"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clickable="true"
         >
    </ImageView>
</FrameLayout>

</bhouse.radiovolumes.ZoomView>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
<bhouse.radiovolumes.ZoomView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"

android:layout_centerInParent="true" >

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/zoomLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/view_scan"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clickable="true"
         >
    </ImageView>
</FrameLayout>

</bhouse.radiovolumes.ZoomView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you make bad usage of getView method

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){

        ViewHolder holder;

        if (convertView == null){
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.list_view_scan, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.scanView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.view_scan);
            holder.frameLayout = (FrameLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.zoomLayout);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
        }

        // Then do operation here on your view holder
        // ...

        return convertView;

}
```

And If you start this project now, think about using RecyclerView instead of ListView.

Now as it is ok with that, you need to clear your Framelayout before adding your ImageViews by calling removeAllViews() method, if not old views remains in it.

Comment: Thank you very much for your interest.

1/ I formatted the code. Is it readible?
2/ You are right my pattern was not correct. However, the problem remains: interestingly, vector images (cylindre 2) seem to be re-used in incorrect slices. For instant, vector for position 1 can be found also in slice with position 5. 
I think it has to do with the recycling of view as new imageView are created. I can't figure out how, though. Any help appreciated !

Comment: yes !! the option is also available in layout editor

Comment: I've updated my answer, hope it'll solve your problem

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I had already made a few tries with framelayout.removeAllViews(), without success. 
It turn out that Picasso was messing everything up. Removing use of Picasso and simply loading a new scan image after clearing the layout did the trick. 
Thank you again. Should I edit my code?

Comment: Its up to you ! happy to had helping you to find the way